# type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dart, model

I'm getting an exception when trying to get the data from the API. When there's data in the response it works perfectly, but if the response is empty it throws this exception. Does anyone know how to handle this?

This is how the response looks like-

When there's data:

[image]

When it's empty:

[image]

The exception I'm getting:

[image]

My model class:

```
import 'dart:convert';

TransactionsList transactionsListFromJson(String str) {
  final jsonData = json.decode(str);
  return TransactionsList.fromJson(jsonData);
}

String transactionsListToJson(TransactionsList data) {
  final dyn = data.toJson();
  return json.encode(dyn);
}

class TransactionsList {
  String? type;
  String? message;
  int? paidTotalRecords;
  PaidTotalAmount? paidTotalAmount;
  List<PaidRecordDatum>? paidRecordData;

  TransactionsList(
      {this.type,
      this.message,
      this.paidTotalRecords,
      this.paidTotalAmount,
      this.paidRecordData});

  factory TransactionsList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      TransactionsList(
        type: json["type"],
        message: json["message"],
        paidTotalRecords: json["paid_TotalRecords"],
        paidTotalAmount: PaidTotalAmount.fromJson(json["paid_TotalAmount"]),
        paidRecordData: List<PaidRecordDatum>.from(
            json["paid_recordData"].map((x) => PaidRecordDatum.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "message": message,
        "paid_TotalRecords": paidTotalRecords,
        "paid_TotalAmount": paidTotalAmount!.toJson(),
        "paid_recordData":
            List<dynamic>.from(paidRecordData!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class PaidRecordDatum {
  int? tcid;
  String? crn;
  String? reqCurrency;
  String? reqAmount;
  String? paidCurrency;
  String? paidAmount;
  String? createdAt;
  String? fromName;
  String? toName;
  String? toEmail;
  String? type;
  String? typeNote;

  PaidRecordDatum({
    this.tcid,
    this.crn,
    this.reqCurrency,
    this.reqAmount,
    this.paidCurrency,
    this.paidAmount,
    this.createdAt,
    this.fromName,
    this.toName,
    this.toEmail,
    this.type,
    this.typeNote,
  });

  factory PaidRecordDatum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      PaidRecordDatum(
        tcid: json["tcid"],
        crn: json["CRN"],
        reqCurrency: json["req_currency"],
        reqAmount: json["req_amount"],
        paidCurrency: json["paid_currency"],
        paidAmount: json["paid_amount"],
        createdAt: json["created_at"],
        fromName: json["from_name"],
        toName: json["to_name"],
        toEmail: json["to_email"],
        type: json["type"],
        typeNote: json["type_note"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "tcid": tcid,
        "CRN": crn,
        "req_currency": reqCurrency,
        "req_amount": reqAmount,
        "paid_currency": paidCurrency,
        "paid_amount": paidAmount,
        "created_at": createdAt,
        "from_name": fromName,
        "to_name": toName,
        "to_email": toEmail,
        "type": type,
        "type_note": typeNote,
      };
}

class PaidTotalAmount {
  String? lkr;

  PaidTotalAmount({
    this.lkr,
  });

  factory PaidTotalAmount.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      PaidTotalAmount(
        lkr: json["LKR"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "LKR": lkr,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your PaidTotalAmount is list when it is empty but when it have data it use List DataType. You can ask your backend to fix it and make single data type. You can also tweak on runtime, I am returning null when it is empty

```dart
paidTotalAmount: () {
  try {
    return PaidTotalAmount.fromJson(json["paid_TotalAmount"]);
  } catch (e) {
    log(e.toString());
  }
}(),
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it throws the same exception to this line in your code "return PaidTotalAmount.fromJson(data);"

Comment: can you include the error message

Comment: _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Comment: ok, try current one, it will return null by default on exception

Comment: glad to help, but it would be better you ask your backend